# Loading related entities multiple branches and multiple levels

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm writing an application where I need the `EvaluationRounds` with a particular student.

Everything starts with the project. A project has many groups. A group has many members, but one member can also be in many groups. This is done by the associative table `ProjectGroupMembers` On the other hand, a project has many evaluation rounds.

Currently I have this linq statement:

```
from r in _context.EvaluationRounds.Include(e => e.EvaluationRoundProject.ProjectGroups.Select(pg => pg.Persons))
                                   .Include(e => e.Evaluations)
     join g in _context.ProjectGroups on r.ProjectId equals g.ProjectId
     join m in _context.ProjectGroupMembers on g.ProjectGroupId equals m.GroupId
     where m.PersonId == studentId && r.EvaluationRoundStartTime < DateTime.Now && r.EvaluationRoundEndTime > DateTime.Now
     select r
```

We use the using statement to dispose of the dbcontext as soon as we have the list.

The problem is that the `EvaluationRoundProject` and its relatives are not loaded with the `EvaluationRounds`. This is what we get:

> '((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EvaluationRound_7400F2ED13550F1E92655A802808E4B94D454A30979C80D0EEED31D0CB7D7005)(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(activeEvaluationrounds).Items[0])).EvaluationRoundProject'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

I have tried:

```
from r in _context.EvaluationRounds.Include("EvaluationRoundProject").Include(e => e.EvaluationRoundProject.ProjectGroups.Select(pg => pg.Persons)).Include(e => e.Evaluations)
     join g in _context.ProjectGroups on r.ProjectId equals g.ProjectId
     join m in _context.ProjectGroupMembers on g.ProjectGroupId equals m.GroupId
     where m.PersonId == studentId && r.EvaluationRoundStartTime < DateTime.Now && r.EvaluationRoundEndTime > DateTime.Now
     select r
```

and also

```
from r in _context.EvaluationRounds.Include(a => a.EvaluationRoundProject).Include(e => e.EvaluationRoundProject.ProjectGroups.Select(pg => pg.Persons)).Include(e => e.Evaluations)
     join g in _context.ProjectGroups on r.ProjectId equals g.ProjectId
     join m in _context.ProjectGroupMembers on g.ProjectGroupId equals m.GroupId
     where m.PersonId == studentId && r.EvaluationRoundStartTime < DateTime.Now && r.EvaluationRoundEndTime > DateTime.Now
     select r
```

**Edit**: The evaluations also do not load into the evaluationround

**Edit2**: this is the whole using code

```
using (_context = new PeerEvaluationContext())
{
    var activeEvaluationrounds = from r in _context.EvaluationRounds.Include(e => e.EvaluationRoundProject.ProjectGroups.Select(pg => pg.Persons)).Include(e => e.Evaluations)
                                         join g in _context.ProjectGroups on r.ProjectId equals g.ProjectId
                                         join m in _context.ProjectGroupMembers on g.ProjectGroupId equals m.GroupId
                                         where m.PersonId == studentId && r.EvaluationRoundStartTime < DateTime.Now && r.EvaluationRoundEndTime > DateTime.Now
                                         select r;
    return activeEvaluationrounds.ToList();
}
```

**Edit 3**: this problem occurs because lazy loading is used. But I went looking on the internet and they said the `include` part would take care of this.

Comment: use .ToList() ?

Comment: already doing that, added the information into the question

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that the error occured because of lazy loading. `EvaluationRound` or `EvaluationRoundProject` entities have  navigation properties which is `virtual` and EF is attempting to load data in somewhere after `_context` already disposed. So, would you try to use another class to select query;

```
var activeEvaluationrounds = from r in _context.EvaluationRounds.Include(e => e.EvaluationRoundProject.ProjectGroups.Select(pg => pg.Persons)).Include(e => e.Evaluations)
    join g in _context.ProjectGroups on r.ProjectId equals g.ProjectId
    join m in _context.ProjectGroupMembers on g.ProjectGroupId equals m.GroupId
    where m.PersonId == studentId && r.EvaluationRoundStartTime < DateTime.Now && r.EvaluationRoundEndTime > DateTime.Now
    select new EvaluationRoundDto
    {
        EvaluationRoundId = r.EvaluationRoundId,
        ProjectId = r.ProjectId
        //etc.
    };
```

I think you should check `virtual` navigation properties and where are they used after context already disposed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. lazy loading is indeed used because in most cases we need evaluationround but not its project. i will try this solution but everywhere i look, like here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx), they say the ´include part´ will load the project into the evaluationround so you can acces them. so i thought this would be enough, why is it not?

Comment: I tried this and i get the error  `System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'AP.PeerEvaluations.DAL.Contexts.EvaluationRound' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'`

Comment: You should create a new class to select query like "select new EvaluationRoundDto". Not use the entity class.